# How can I see my Restricted friends list on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Each time I post, it comes up with "friends except restricted". I have no "restricted" list on the left hand side of the screen where lists appear.

I did have a restricted list ages ago but now I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem with my girlfriend, we couldn't figure this out.  For us - in July 2017 - this is how I solved it.  (FB changes their UI so often, it's difficult to post a lasting fix, but here goes) ....

1. On your friend's page whose posts you can't see, have them logged in
2. Have them go to your profile page
3. Click your Friends button
4. Select "Add to another list..."
5. See if "Restricted" list is selected for some reason.  If so, then click it again to hopefully take you off Restricted List.

At least it worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that you currently need to find it. Note, however, that Facebook frequently changes their UI, so these steps may become outdated as some point in the future.

1. Go to the lock icon in the upper-right corner, and click **See More Settings**:

   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. Click on the **Blocking** tab on the left, then click **Edit List** in the **Restricted List** section at the top:

   [image: Screenshot 2]

You will then see a popup dialog with everyone on your Restricted List. You can also add and remove people from the list through this dialog.

Answer (score -2):

Update 5/1/17
From your phone: 
Go to person in questions page
Click friends
Click 'Edit Friend List'
Scroll to the bottom and click 'Restricted'

Comment: As this is Web Applications, we really kind of expect solutions to use the web interface, not a smartphone app.